# How to query Mysql multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'sql', 'abc123');
mysql_select_db('common');
$phone_mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_mobile']);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT phone_mobile FROM leads WHERE phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'"');
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
echo 1;
} else {
echo 0;
}
?>
```

This works; however I have the same column in table "contacts".

Therefore I require to query table(leads) and table(contacts) for same column name(phone_mobile).

**If the phone_mobile is in either "leads" or "contacts" or both then echo result.**

I'm presuming a UNION or JOIN query is in order?

Thanx in advance.

John

Comment: provide the complete DDL of both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use UNION

```
$result = mysql_query('  SELECT phone_mobile FROM (
  SELECT phone_mobile FROM leads WHERE phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'"
  UNION
  SELECT phone_mobile FROM contacts WHERE phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'"
   )t
  GROUP BY phone_mobile ') ;
```

Comment: UNION works from direct query.
I would like to know how to code it for 'mysql_query'

Comment: i dont know what you mean , but you can do it mysql_query also.

Answer (score 0):

Add `contacts` to your query

```
mysql_query("SELECT phone_mobile FROM leads, contacts WHERE phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'");
```

Generally :

```
SELECET 'Column 1'[,'Column 2','Column 3', ...]
FROM 'Table1', [,'Table 2','Table 3', ...]
WHERE 'Condition 1' [AND 'Condition 2' AND 'Column 3', ...]
```

;

If your 'phone_mobile' column have not the same name in 2 tables or more, use this syntaxe :

`SELECT Table1.phone_number_t1, Table2.phone_number_t2`

whereas

`SELECT phone_mobile FROM Table1, Table2`

AND Condtions will be

WHERE Table1.phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'" OR Table2.phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'"

Whereas

WHERE phone_mobile = "'.$phone_mobile.'"

Comment: This doesn't work.

mysql> select phone_mobile from leads,contacts where leads.phone_mobile = '16508571501';
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'phone_mobile' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: `select phone_mobile from leads,contacts where phone_mobile = '16508571501'`

Answer (score 0):

you could

```
 SELECT l.phone_mobile, c.phone_mobile FROM leads l, contacts c WHERE l.phone_mobile = '$phone_mobile' OR c.phone_mobile = '$phone_mobile';
```

then check if either field contains a value.

Comment: This doesn't work.

I get no response for the query and MySQL hangs.

Comment: Query looks correct to me. Perhaps it returns too much results or some other problem arises. Try it directly in mysql to see what error you get.

Comment: on second thought, this might return way too much results so try adding DISTINCT after SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You simply write below query

```
$query = "select phone_mobile from leads,contacts where leads.phone_mobile = '".$phone_mobile."'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Mysql error says : ".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
  echo 1;
} else {
  echo 0; 
}
```

Comment: This also don't work.

mysql> select phone_mobile from leads,contacts where leads.phone_mobile = '16508571501';

ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'phone_mobile' in field list is ambiguous
mysql>

Comment: Replace with this query $query = "select leads.phone_mobile as leadphone,contacts.phone_mobile as contmobile from leads,contacts where leads.phone_mobile = '".$phone_mobile."'";

Answer (score 0):

try Using COALESCE,

```
SELECT COALESCE(l.phone_mobile,c.phone_mobile) mobilePhone  FROM leads l,
contacts c 
WHERE l.phone_mobile='".$phone_mobile."'
```

Comment: This don't work. It returns an "Empty Set"

mysql> SELECT COALESCE(l.phone_mobile,c.phone_mobile) mobilePhone  FROM leads l,contacts c WHERE l.phone_mobile= '16508571501';
Empty set (0.00 sec)